# Django Tutorial (from django website) part 5 - Admin Panel strange behavior

Tags: python, django

I started learning Django recently and am having a strange problem with the tutorial..

For some reason, If I query a specific 'poll' by using the shell, the was_published_recently method returns 'true'.

I've also wrote the test to check if pub_date is "between the time one-day-ago and now", and it returns 'true'.. (all tests passed ok)

However, when I list that poll in the admin panel, it returns 'false' ("Published recently?" column)

[image: admin panel screenshot]

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code, please?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my `polls/models.py`:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(hours=2) <= self.pub_date < now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

And here is the `polls/tests.py` file:

```
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase

from polls.models import Poll

class PollMethodTests(TestCase):

    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_poll(self):
        future_poll = Poll(pub_date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30))
        self.assertEqual(future_poll.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_old_poll(self):
        old_poll = Poll(pub_date=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
        self.assertEqual(old_poll.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_recent_poll(self):
        recent_poll = Poll(pub_date=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1))
        self.assertEqual(recent_poll.was_published_recently(), True)
```

And the `polls/admin.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,          {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information',    {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['question']

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

and `polls/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from polls.models import Choice, Poll

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Devuelve las ultimas 5 encuestas """
        return Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay poll voting form
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "Please choose an option",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Siempre devolver un HttpResponseRedirect despues de trabajar con
        # POSTs. Esto evita que la informacion se inserte dos veces si el
        # usuario le da al BACK.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Comment: what does you polls admin.py file look like?

Comment: I've added it to the end of my question. Thanks in advance, chawk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set you Timezone in settings.py correctly?
I think the tests are using the systemtime. But the Webinterface is using the timezone you set.

Comment: is that an answer or a comment?

Comment: Since i dont have enough reputation I can't add a comment

Comment: if he runs `./manager.py test`, the test use django's timezone

Comment: But he imports datetime and adds datetime.timedelta to Djangos timezone.now(). These are two different sources of time, aren't they?

Comment: Ahh I see it now, don't use datetime and timezone together, just timezone :)

Comment: oh.. so is this tutorial supposed to be wrong? :(
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial05/#fixing-the-bug

Comment: Wow.. thank you @user2862506, that did the trick! I've updated my TIME_ZONE variable to 'Europe/Madrid' and everything seems to be working now! :)